# Lync presence suddenly stop showing inside sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, office-integration

I have SharePoint server 2013 with SP1 , and we are using Microsoft lync 2010. Previously the Lync presence status was showing up inside SharePoint sites. But today this stop working, although we did not make any changes to our environment, so can anyone advice what might be causing this problem please?

currently we will get an empty box for the status as follow, baring in mind that i am singin to lync from my machine:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you are asking for Lync2010 => SP2013 relation issue, but maybe the below helps you:

[Sharepoint 2013 Presence blank](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89896/sharepoint-2013-presence-blank)

> Is presence still enabled on your webapp?
>
> Browse to central admin > Manage web applications > choose your web
>   app > General Settings > Person Name Actions and Presence Settings
>
> > With additional actions and Online Status enabled, online presence information is displayed next to member names and the additional
> >     actions appear when users right-click on a member name anywhere on
> >     this site.
>
> Enable additional actions and Online Status for members: Yes

Comment from @LeeHarrison in relation to above quote:

> Hmm, well it was enabled. I disabled it anyway and then re-enabled it
>   and that seems to have fixed it. Not sure why this occurred, but
>   thanks for pointing me in the right direction. –  Lee Harrison

Comment: i have this already enabled, so i disable it then re-enable it ,, but this did not fix the problem...

Comment: i have noted that this problem is happening on some machines not all of them..

Comment: @johnG Can it be a simple case of the users viewing the site have not logged on to Lync? If the user viewing the site is not logged on to Lync the Lync-status for others cannot be shown.

Comment: as i said before users are login to their local lync..

Comment: not sure what happened, but i have installed Visio 2010 and after the install the lync presence status worked again !!!