# Presence not displayed on Person or group field

Tags: 2010, person, presence-indication

I have a SharePoint 2010 site collection where the People or Group fields like "*Created By*" or "*Modified by*" show only the name of the user, without the presence dot next to it.

However, I have other site collections where this is working properly.

Where can this be activated at site collection level or how can I troubleshoot this issue if it's not working properly?

Comment: Have you check any error in console?

Comment: No, how can this be checked?

Comment: Open your browser console and hover your mouse pointer on presence icon and check any error occur..

Comment: That is a global setting, so it should work for all sites or any. Try anyway by disabling and enabling this settings from Central Admin, as suggested in this other answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/89912/16984

Comment: Hi Massimo, you are right, it was disabled on the web application. If you put this as an answer I will accept for you. Thank you.